# How to connect to a mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, tornado-motor, database

I'm using `mongoLabs` to host my database and I want to connect to it from my app.

I'm also using the `Motor` module in `pyMongo`. I'm unsure where to instantiate the connection.

For instance I know that if the database was on same local machine as the app I would do this:

```
 database = motor.MotorClient().open_sync().myDatabase
```

The mongoLab site says to include the following `uri` in the driver:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds047057.mongolab.com:47057/myDatabase
```

But I cannot see how to create the connection to this database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like MotorClient takes the same arguments as MongoClient:

[https://github.com/ajdavis/mongo-python-driver/blob/motor/motor/**init**.py#L782](https://github.com/ajdavis/mongo-python-driver/blob/motor/motor/__init__.py#L782)

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

Given that, you should be able to use the URI like so:

```
database = motor.MotorClient("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds047057.mongolab.com:47057/myDatabase").open_sync().myDatabase
```

Answer (score 2):

You should to specify connection settings for MotorClient following these manuals:
MotorClient takes the same constructor arguments as MongoClient, as well as, http://emptysquare.net/motor/pymongo/api/motor/motor_client.html#motor.MotorClient, 
http://emptysquare.net/motor/pymongo/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient

> "The host parameter can be a full mongodb URI, in addition to a simple
>   hostname. It can also be a list of hostnames or URIs. Any port
>   specified in the host string(s) will override the port parameter. If
>   multiple mongodb URIs containing database or auth information are
>   passed, the last database, username, and password present will be
>   used. For username and passwords reserved characters like ‘:’, ‘/’,
>   ‘+’ and ‘@’ must be escaped following RFC 2396."

```
db =  database = motor.MotorClient('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds047057.mongolab.com:47057/myDatabase
').open_sync().myDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have got a bit outdated, so the correct way according to the docs and as worked for me:

```
import motor.motor_asyncio
import asyncio
from asyncio import coroutine
db = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient().database_name
```

https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html
 https://github.com/mongodb/motor/blob/master/doc/tutorial-asyncio.rst